# foreach get subarray

Tags: php, mongodb, foreach

I am having an issue with the following code below.

```
if ($cursor->count() > 0)
        {
            $test = array();
            // iterate through the results
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
            $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }
            //print_r($test);
            foreach($test as $d) {
                print_r($d);    
                $current_name = $d[0]['personal']['name'];
           }
        }
```

but when I in my mongodb I have

```
array("personal"=>array("name"=>"rusty"));
```

Comment: why [0] ? in `$current_name = $d[0]['personal']['name'];`

Comment: What is the OP of commented `print_r` post some sample array or object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify to :

```
 foreach($test as $d) 
 {
            print_r($d);    
            $current_name = $d['personal']['name'];
 }
```